# submit a form whose value is changing

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have a form in that i am getting the initial value of form from mysql and then javascript changes the value (every second that value increases by 1 ) but when i submit the form it submits the initial value what i have got from mysql .

please tell how to submit the updated value for example if i have retrieved 40 as form value from MySQL  then it keeps on increasing but as in form value is coming from MySQL when i submit it submits 40 only but in actual my form value increases every second please tell how to submit updated value in MySQL. here is my code.

Comment: i have already shared complete php code and in previous mail i have given javascript as well

Comment: my form script is also there in the code i have mentioned above. please help

Comment: It works fine for me, not sure what the issue is. What do you get when you check the value of `$Time_Spent1` before sending it to the database?

Comment: i am getting the same initial value in database . i want the incremented value in database.

Comment: see in your case also its not working as when you submit in echo it shows that you have submitted latest value but in form value it should come the updated value but its coming 40 only . suppose you submit 90 then in echo its dispalying that you have submitted 90 but when it refreshes then in form field it should start from 90 not from 40

Comment: can you show me the updated value in form value field??

Comment: @wesley please give the code what you have used

Comment: @wesley will you please share the code you have used . please share its my code only just soething i am missing just i want to compare.

Comment: I already answered your question with all the code you need.

Comment: @WESLEY YOUR CODES ARE NOT CORRECT AS YOU HAVENOT USED MYSQL TO STORE THE DATA , U HAVE USED SESSION TO STORE SO WHEN I OPEN NEW PAGE IT STARTS FROM ZERO

Comment: Did you even read the answer? I didn't use `$_SESSION` anywhere... The demo I put up (and took down) was only to show that the `$_POST` value was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized your problem: You are fetching the value *before* the `UPDATE`, so you are always getting the old value. Make sure you run the `SELECT` *after* the `UPDATE` so you can get the new value. Try something like this:

```
// Only update if a value was posted
if (isset($_POST['Time_Spent1']))
{
    // Cast to integer or use mysql_real_escape_string() here to protect the query
    $new_value = (integer) $_POST['Time_Spent1'];
    sql_query( "update jcow_accounts set Time_Spent = '{$new_value}' where id = '{$client['id']}' " );
}

// Run SELECT afterwards, in case the value was updated
$res = sql_query("select * from jcow_accounts where id='{$client['id']}'");

$row = sql_fetch_array($res);

$Time = $row['Time_Spent'];

echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<p>Earning: <input name="Time_Spent1"  value="'.$Time.'" id="Time_Spent1"   type="text" size="7"  /></p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>'
```

So, it was nothing to do with the `$_POST` value, the value that you used to repopulate the form input from the database was "old". There's plenty of other things I could nitpick about the code, and I'm tempted to, but this should get you moving forward.

Comment: I'm guessing `sql_query()` is either supposed to be something else (like `mysql_query()`), or it's a user defined function...

Comment: YOU ROCKS THANKS A LOT ITS WORKING LIKE A CHARM LOVE YOU BROTHER. CAN I HAVE YOUR EMAILS ADDRESS ???